# Returning list of list values (consolidated)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, list, foreach

I want to be able to return a list of all "list values" coming from the query.. 'query' below returns  multiple rows of results back from db, each as an item in a list. A sample result back from db would look like...

sample query results when I put break point: (this is what first line of code below 'query' returns from db)

> 1. Name = John ; Address = 1230, Ewded ; listOfCities = "NY, CH, LA"
> 2. Name = Eric; Address = 12 , Ewded ; listOfCities = "BO, SE, OR"

Code:

```
        List<Index.Result> query = getresultsbackfromdb();
       // query content at this point looks like above 1,2 

        List<string> result = new List<string>();            

        foreach (var item in query)
        {      

            results.Add(item.listCities);

            //'results' list takes in string and not a list
            //How do I return a consolidated list of items

        }

        return result; // this should have ""NY, CH, LA, BO, SE, OR"
        //I am trying to get a list of all cities from 1,2 included in
        //one single list.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is method in a `List` that allows you to add multiple items

```
foreach (var item in query)
{      
    results.AddRange(item.listCities);  
}
```

Docs for [List.AddRange Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx).

Also, just in case if you need to filter out some repeated items, you can use a [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) LINQ method.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code based on `Split Method`

```
var result = yourString.Split(',');


var input = "NY, CH, LA";
var result = input.Split(',');
```

And you can save this value in `List<object>`

```
var list = new List<object>();
list.Add(result );
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the `AddRange` and `string.Split` methods

```
results.AddRange(string.Split(',', item.ListCities));
```

`string.Split` will split the string into an array wherever it finds the given character, and add range will add all items in an array to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var result = query.SelectMany(x => x.listOfCities.Split(','));
```

Or use

```
var result = query.SelectMany(x => x.listOfCities.Split(',')).Distinct();
```

to get the list without duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

If you like Linq then you could do this one line:

```
using System.Linq;

List<string> result = query.SelectMany(s => s.listCities).ToList();
```

(This does essentially the same thing as oleksii's AddRange.)